# Google Apps Script: How do I check for an empty filter/variable?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been working on some Google Apps Script code that filters a sheet based on specific criteria.

An email is sent out with the filtered data appearing in a HTML table.

I want to make it so that this email is only sent out if there is data within that filter.

I've tried the following:

```
var newdata = tableRangeValues.filter(function(item) {
  return item[0] === filt && item[1] === endDate;
});

if(newdata !== "") {
  GmailApp.sendEmail(
    "someemail@somedomain.com", 
    "New EMEA Distribution Onboarding Request(s)",
    "You have received the following new Request(s). Please see the details below.",
    {htmlBody: htmlForEmail}
  );
}
```

(only posted the relevant snippet)

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Does anyone know a way to make it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*The `Array.prototype.filter()`function has an array return, so rather than comparing it to empty string you can check its length and only make the call if it is not zero.*

#### Code:

Just change your if condition from:

```
if (newdata !== "") {
  //...
}
```

to:

```
if (newdata.length != 0) {
  //...
}
```

#### References:

- [`Array.prototype.filter()` - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)